# CastError: Cast to Boolean failed for value Express.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Good day Experts,

My problem is.. how to apply a "false" value if the value of the checkbox is 'null' or empty, it save on my database only when the value or check box is true.. what about the false statement? im newbie in express routes. how to implement it im using mongodb and mongooses schema...  here below is my router post

```
router.post('/addCustomer', async (req, res) => {
  const { name, organisation, notifIncident, notifChange, notifMaintenance } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body)
  try {
    let customer = new Customer({
      name,
      organisation,
      notifMaintenance,
      notifIncident,
      notifChange,
    });
    customer = await customer.save();
    res.json(customer);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
    console.log(err)
  }
  console.log(req.body)
})
```

and here is the mongoose schema:

```
const CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  organisation: {
    type: String
  },
  notifMaintenance: {
    type: Boolean
  },
  notifIncident: {
    type: Boolean
  },
  notifChange: {
    type: Boolean
  },
});


const Customer = mongoose.model('customer', CustomerSchema);
```

the notifIncident, notifChange and notifMaintenance is check box on the frontend..
it saves when those three are being checked, and if unchecked i've got and error casting value: null" instead of false.. it should be thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use secondary variable. Ex -

```
const maintenance = !!notifMaintenance;
```

Now if notifMaintenance is null then ***!!*** casts the value into a boolean one and if notifMaintenance is true or false then the converted value will be same as original one.

Note: ***!!*** is helpful for casting falsy values into boolean type.

Comment: const { notifChange = !!notifChange, notifIncident = !!notifIncident, notifMaintenance = !!notifMaintenance };
[0]         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[0]
[0] SyntaxError: Missing initializer in destructuring declaration.... this is what i've got an error when inserting secondary variable

Comment: Don't destructure it. Just declare another variable and assign it to that.

Comment: Or use let during destructuring and inside destructuring if you do abc = 123 then you are telling the language if abc is not present assign 123 to the abc, the problem for you will be that even if you use let instead of const then also you'll get null because null is also a user-defined value.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably just add a check before proceeding to save:

```
    router.post('/addCustomer', async (req, res) => {
      const { name, organisation, notifIncident, notifChange, notifMaintenance } = req.body;

      if( !notifIncident || !notifChange || !notifMaintenance) {
       //maybe throw an error, or send a server code that notifies the front
      }

      console.log(req.body)
      try {
        let customer = new Customer({
          name,
          organisation,
          notifMaintenance,
          notifIncident,
          notifChange,
        });
        customer = await customer.save();
        res.json(customer);
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
        console.log(err)
      }
      console.log(req.body)
    })
```

although, ideally this should be handled on the front end with a similar check done before submitting, and an error rendered to the use that some required data has not been provided.

Comment: 0] MongoDB Connected
[0] { customerId: '',
[0]   name: 'Leon Shane',
[0]   organisation: 'Customer3',
[0]   notifIncident: '',
[0]   notifChange: '',
[0]   notifMaintenance: '' }
that is the output,, but when i check on the check box it will save on database

Comment: <FormGroup check inline>
              <Label check>
                <Input
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={notifIncident}
                  onChange={(newValue) => {
                    setRecipientFormData('notifIncident', newValue.target.checked);
                  }}      -that is the front end

Comment: what if you set `notifIncident` to false as it's inital value since you will be updating it to true once it's checked with ` setRecipientFormData`?

Comment: I've tried value={false}, but it doesn't recognize and still got the same error... also been tried to set in my reducer and got the value of false... it is kinda weird when the checkbox is checked, the value still 'false'.... if im set in redux reducer....